# Prevent browser back button after login and logout in oracle apex

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

In Oracle APEX, how do I prevent a user from navigating back to the login page from the home page using browser back button after login, and then navigating back to home page from the login page after logout? I tried the following JavaScript code

```
window.history.forward();
```

But it did not give me the expected results.

Comment: There is no reliable way to disable the browser Back button, and it is considered bad practice to do so. But you should ensure that if users do use it, they don't get into difficulty or get access to something they shouldn't.  What is the problem with them using the Back button that you are concerned woth?

Comment: actually, after login, i can go back to login page from home page using the navigation button in the browser . Then again without typing the password and user name if I press the browser 'go forward' button I can go to the home page having the same previous session.

Comment: Yes, but that's because you have already logged in.  You'll find you can do exactly the same on the APEX Builder home and login pages!

Comment: I checked and you are correct in the case of loging in , but in the logout case, after logout if I click the browser back button It do not goes to the previous page and redirects to login page.

Comment: That is because you need to be an authenticated user to go to the home page - i.e. the security setting for the page is "Page Requires Authentication".  You should do the same for your home page, then the logged out user will be redirected to the login page there too.

Comment: New info. Thank you. will check this tomorrow